# I need to get the title for a news article using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium webdriver to get the html from www.cnn.com 
Currently, I'm able to get the headlines from cnn but I was wondering if I could save the content into a text file and then search for specific headlines to print out.

My python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.cnn.com')

content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html").text
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Google is your friend : http://www.seleniumstutorial.com/getting-the-source-of-the-page-in-selenium-with-python/

Comment: beautiful soup will be better for this

Comment: Have you considered to use the RSS feed?

Comment: Can you update the question with what exactly you mean by _to get the html from www.cnn.com_, _able to get the headlines_, _save the content into a text file_ and _then search for specific headlines_?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium won't help if you are reading from text file as its APIs work in browser context using webdriver protocol.

If you want to save the whole html content in to a text file and then read headlines, you can make use of BeautifulSoup module. Here's an example.

```
with open("htmlcontent.txt") as f: 
  html_data = f.readlines() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, "html.parser")

for elem in soup.select("h1"):
    print(elem.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) is definitely what best fits your case. But if you want to use Selenium, you could loop through headlines and extract their text using the Selenium driver (not from the file directly).

Looking at CNN's website, `cd__headline-text` is the class name applied to headlines, so you could get them like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.cnn.com')

for headline in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('cd__headline-text'):
    print(headline.text)
```

Output:

> Asia's strongmen adopt 'fake news' to slam media
>   Fitness tracking app reveals info on remote military bases
>   Seven rescued, 43 missing week after ferry sinks in Pacific
>   ...